# Heroku Stripe Connect Callback request.env['omniauth.auth'] is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, omniauth, stripe-connect

I have implemented the stripe connect in Ruby on Rails

Ruby 2.4.0
Rails 5.1.1

When I run the flow on my local machine everything works great. But When I run the flow on heroku server request.env['omniauth.auth'] is always nil.

I am using custom callback for stripe.

I have tried to investigate the issue and found a difference. When I run it on my local machine I see these logs

(stripe_connect) Request phase initiated.

and after I authorize from stripe I see this

(stripe_connect) Callback phase initiated.

and my code works properly.

But When I run the flow on Heroku. I can see (stripe_connect) Request phase initiated. but there is no log about (stripe_connect) Callback phase initiated. and request.env['omniauth.auth'] is nil.